# How to correctly insert a jsonb into postgresql using a Java PreparedStatement

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection, jsonb

I have a postgresql database table `mytable` with a `jsonb` column `mycolumn`.
Now, I would like to insert a new row using Java and a PreparedStatement

```
public void insertRow(JSONObject json, Connection connection) {
   PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (mycolumn) VALUES (?));
   ps.setObject(position++, json, Types.OTHER);
   ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

However, if the json contains a single quote `'` somewhere, like this example:

```
{
    "foo": "'bar (notice the single quote in front)"
}
```

this results in an `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated string literal started at position...`

Thus, this could be exploited for SQL injection despite having used a `PreparedStatement`.
How to correctly escape the JSON data?

Postgres-Driver: 42.7.1
Open-JDK: 17